# ReactJS и UIkit 3.6.5: не прослушивается клик в модальном окне

Tags: reactjs, uikit

Пишу приложение на ReactJs. Пытаюсь добавить и настроить модальное окно из UIkit. Проблема в том, что не срабатывает обработчик клика по кнопке("Сохранить"), событие клика в принципе не прослушивается внутри модального окна. Выношу кнопку за модальное окно - всё работает(в консоли появляется сообщение). Это баг или я что-то неправильно делаю? Большое спасибо за внимание!

```
 return(
    <>
        <button className="uk-button uk-button-primary" uk-toggle="target: #modal-save">ОПУБЛИКОВАТЬ</button>
        
        <div id="modal-save" uk-modal="true">
            <div className="uk-modal-dialog uk-modal-body">                    
                <p>Уверены, что желаете сохранить изменения?</p>
                <p className="uk-text-right">                                               
                    <button className="uk-button uk-button-default uk-modal-close" type="button">Отмена</button>
                    <button
                     className="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-modal-close"
                     type="button"
                     onClick={() => console.log("Click")}>Сохранить</button>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>            
        
    </>
);
```

Comment: Ответ получен на англ ресурсе: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65443562/reactjs-and-uikit-3-6-5-click-event-isnt-fired-inside-modal-window

Answer (score 0):

`<div id="modal-save" uk-modal="true">` это, исправь на это

`<div id="modal-save" uk-modal="true" container="false">`

Это баг UIKit 3 версии, я не знаю как это работает